Issue with displaying video in PyQt6
I am trying to create an application in PyQt6 that displays a video from a webcam. When I run the code, it shows an empty window. Can you help me understand what I am doing wrong?
Source Code:
from PyQt6 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QSizePolicy, QHBoxLayout
from PyQt6.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt6.QtCore import pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot, Qt, QThread
import sys
import cv2
import numpy as np

class VideoThread(QThread):
    change_pixmap_signal = pyqtSignal(np.ndarray)

    def run(self):
        cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        if not cam.isOpened():
            print("Error opening video file")
            return
        while True:
            ret, frame = cam.read()
            if not ret:
                break
            frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)  # Отзеркаливание по вертикали
            self.change_pixmap_signal.emit(frame)  # Отправляем кадровое изображение в основной поток
        cam.release()

class MovingApp(QThread):
    change_pixmap_signal = pyqtSignal(np.ndarray)

    def run(self):
        cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        if not cam.isOpened():
            print("Error opening video file")
            return
        backSub = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(history=100, varThreshold=16, detectShadows=True)
        
        while True:
            ret, frame = cam.read()
            if not ret:
                break
            
            fg_mask = backSub.apply(frame)
            contours, _ = cv2.findContours(fg_mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
            min_contour_area = 450
            large_contours = [cnt for cnt in contours if cv2.contourArea(cnt) > min_contour_area]
            frame_out = frame.copy()
            for cnt in large_contours:
                x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
                frame_out = cv2.rectangle(frame_out, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 200), 3)
            
            self.change_pixmap_signal.emit(frame_out)  # Отправляем обработанный кадр в основной поток

        cam.release()

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('image.ico'))
        self.setWindowTitle('Project')
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.video_label = QLabel(self)
        self.video_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        self.video_label.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding)

        self.thread = None
        
        button_layout = QVBoxLayout()  # Добавляем макет для кнопок
        button2 = QPushButton('Отслеживание\nдвижения')
        button2.setCheckable(True)
        button2.toggled.connect(self.toggle_moving_app)  # Изменяем соединение на toggle
        button2.setFixedSize(220, 140)
        button_layout.addWidget(button2)

        layout.addLayout(button_layout)
        layout.addWidget(self.video_label)

        # Запускаем поток видео по умолчанию
        self.start_video_thread()
        self.showMaximized()

    def toggle_moving_app(self, checked):
        """Переключаем между потоками видео и обработки."""
        if checked:
            self.start_moving_thread()
        else:
            self.start_video_thread()

    def start_video_thread(self):
        """Запускаем поток для простого видео."""
        if self.thread is not None:
            self.thread.quit()
            self.thread.wait()  # Обязательно ждем завершения потока
        self.thread = VideoThread()
        self.thread.change_pixmap_signal.connect(self.update_image)
        self.thread.start()

    def start_moving_thread(self):
        """Запускаем поток для работы с движением."""
        if self.thread is not None:
            self.thread.quit()
            self.thread.wait()  # Обязательно ждем завершения потока
        self.thread = MovingApp()

        self.thread.change_pixmap_signal.connect(self.update_image)
        self.thread.start()

    @pyqtSlot(np.ndarray)
    def update_image(self, frame):
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (950, 750))
        h, w, ch = frame.shape
        bytes_per_line = ch * w
        q_img = QtGui.QImage(frame.data, w, h, bytes_per_line, QtGui.QImage.Format.Format_RGB888)
        self.video_label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(q_img))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


The video from the webcam should be displayed in the application window, but when I run the code, the application window is empty, and the video is not displayed. The console outputs the following message:
Error opening video file

Technical Details:

Python 3.9
PyQt 6.1.1
OpenCV 4.5.3
Operating System: Windows 10


are you opening the same video device twice at the same time?

[mre] required. if VideoCapture can't open device 0, then all the Qt stuff is irrelevant. find out whether that works at all.
